# not able to mock component methods using jest

Tags: jestjs

everything is latest

```
"jest": "^21.1.0",
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0"
"react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
"enzyme": "^3.1.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
```

I have a component and a test like below

```js
//component
class ToggleCheckbox  extends Component{
   onChange=()=>{}
   render(){
      return <div> <button onClick={this.onChange} >click</button> </div> 
   }
}

//test
  it('spy', () => {
    //arrange
    const spy = jest.fn().mockImplementation( ()=>{
      console.log(`spy called`);
    })
    const wrapper = shallow(<ToggleCheckbox />);   
    wrapper.instance().onChange = spy
    wrapper.update(); //Forces a re-render.
    //act
    // wrapper.instance().onChange()
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

    //assert
    expect(spy).toBeCalled(); // this will fail but I don't know why;
  });
```

the assertion will fail but I don't know why.

I know i'm testing jest , or enzyme here rather than testing my code -- as we are doing shallow and no event gets fired in the test; but I want to know what is going on under the hood;
thanks

here is the link to the original question: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4696

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the component is rendered before you spy on it, and so the onClick is already bound to the original.

Here is the solution:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ToggleCheckbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  public onChange() {
    console.log('onChange');
  }
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onChange}>click</button>{' '}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ToggleCheckbox from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('ToggleCheckbox', () => {
  it('spy', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ToggleCheckbox.prototype, 'onChange').mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log(`spy called`);
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<ToggleCheckbox />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47921226/index.spec.tsx (7.557s)
  ToggleCheckbox
    ✓ spy (19ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/47921226/index.spec.tsx:8
    spy called

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.519s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/47921226